# How to prepare stud wall for PVC shower panels

Tags: bathroom

I've recently removed the tiles from my bathroom wall, and the plasterboards all come off too.  So I'm left with a stud wall and no covering.

I plan to fit pvc panelling (polypanel).  How should I prepare the walls?

1. Stick the polypanel straight on the stud work
2. Put up normal plasterboard and stick straight to that
3. Put up normal plasterboard, plaster it, then stick to that
4. Put up something else?

Comment: Rather than "normal plasterboard" you should use water-resistant plasterboard, sometimes referred to as "greenboard" because it often has a green paper cover.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should install cementboard, then mount the panels to that.